# Failed to load the workflow definition for the workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I removed the workflow from the list through workflow settings and now when I tried to open the workflow through the designer to publish it again, I'm receiving this error message.

"Failed to load the workflow definition for the workflow"

How do I get my workflow file now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [hotfix package](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2768343) for SharePoint designer 2013 which fixes that error.

```
failed to load workflow definition.
```

The detailed scenario that raises the issue is similar to what you have mentioned in your question:

> Assume that you use SharePoint Designer 2013 to create a workflow on a
>   SharePoint Server 2013 server. Then, you delete the subscription for
>   the workflow on the server. When you open the workflow in SharePoint
>   Designer 2013, you receive the following error message:

```
failed to load workflow definition.
```

To download and check hotfix details, check [Description of the SharePoint Designer 2013 hotfix package (Spd-x-none.msp): June 11, 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2768343)

Comment: Just to make sure- i have to install this hot-fix on all computers i'm using in my development?

Comment: Not all computers in your dev environment, only the computers that have  SharePoint Designer 2013 installed,

Comment: I tried hotfix suggested but i received this message at the end.
"There are no products affected by this package installed on this system."

Comment: you are using SharePoint Designer 2013 ! right !

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: Is it x64 bit ?

Comment: Yes, I installed this one "spd2013-kb2768343-fullfile-x64-glb.exe"

Comment: no, I talk about the SharePoint designer itself, not the hotfix, I know the hotfix available for SP designer is  x64

Comment: How do i figure it out?

Comment: Okay - I got this info- Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 (15.0.4420.1017) MS0 (15.04420.1017) 32-bit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50347/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-spm).

Comment: try to uninstall the current SharePoint designer 32 and install SP 64 , or at another pc that not have SharePoint designer  , try to install fresh SPD 64  then check the issue , if not solved install hotfix and tell me result

Comment: Thank you M.Qassas. I installed X86 hotfix and it helped. I can edit the workflow now through designer.

Comment: good news , great job  and You are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

TRy clearing SharePoint Designer cache and open a fresh session of the site. Follow below steps to clear the cache :

- Close SPD2013
- Delete everything at
  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
- Delete everything at %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
- Go to SPD2013 options –> General –> Application Options –> Uncheck
  the “Cache site data across SharePoint Designer sessions”

Comment: I actually did that prior to removing workflow from the list, i cleared the cache and unchecked Cache option. I did not open the workflow in designer before removing it from the list. Do you think this could be the reason for the files to be deleted?

Comment: **Clearing SharePoint Designer cache** works perfectly

Comment: This worked for me!  I still have some 2013 workflows that I have to support and SPD was giving me a lot of trouble.  This solution worked perfect!  Thanks!